# Firefox : override Alt + s key shortcut

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working on an application where there are a lot key shortcuts for replication certain UI actions. One of such key shortcut combination is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup',keyUpHandler,false);

function keyUpHandler(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    cellKeys(e,key);
}

function cellKeys(e,key){
    if (e.altKey    && key  === 83) document.getElementById('saveCell').dispatchEvent(mouseclick); //alt + s    
}
```

This key combination seems to work great for all other browsers except Mozilla firefox as this shortcut is used by the browser to open up history menu on top of the page.

I am looking for some workaround for this problem.

**PS**: I cannot use key down event listener and I have to use the same key combination. Also using e.preventDefault() was futile.

Comment: I hope there is no way to do that.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro What security concerns can be incurred by preventing browser to show up some  menu. We override the default browser keyboard shortcuts all the time. User agents these days I guess are smart enough to add checks/block the key shortcuts they think might lead to security breach.

Comment: You are right. I understood something different.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that some browsers will not allow you to capture certain shortcuts! A working example for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut in Mozilla Firefox:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 83){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Shotcut Pressed")
  }
}
```